# ReactJS Navigation

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a sample reactjs application (in learning process). I have a page which list the list of users and a add button to add a new user.

When I click the add button I should navigate to the User Form to create the new user.

After I click the submit button in the user form it should navigate back to the first page where it should list the list of users along with the new user.

How to navigate between pages in react?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You do it with react router. Here is the [react router tutorial](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial).

Your list of users is the first page which is shown when you open the site, thus that is your index page and all other pages are routes.

Thus you can do something like this :

You can create a separate file with your routes :

```
import UserList from 'path/to/user/list';
import AddUserForm from 'path/....';

const routes = (
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={UserList}/>
        <Route path="addUser" component={AddUserForm}/>
    </Route>
);

export default routes;
```

Then your `index.js` should look something like this :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Router, browserHistory} from 'react-router';
import routes from 'path/to/routes'; 

ReactDOM.render(<Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes}/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Here you wrap it under `Router` which comes from `react-router`, and there you pass history prop which you want to use and routes prop. You can use `browserHistory` and `hashHistory`. BrowserHistory shows cleaner urls. With hash history you have something like `someurl.com/#/something`

Now in your app you can do next :

```
export default class App extends Component {
    render() {

        return (
           <div>
              {this.props.children}
           </div>
        );
    }
}
```

`{this.props.children}` renders all routes from routes file, because you have specified App component for the main route.

On the add user button onClick event you can navigate to the add user form with browserHistory, thus :

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router;

.........

onClick(){
    browserHistory.push("/addUser");
}

.......
render(){
   return (
       //Userlist with the button
       <button onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}>Add New user</button>
   );
}
```

And then on button click on add user form, the same process, you only need to navigate to the index route with `"/"`, thus :

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router;

.........

onClick(){
    //Your code to add user to the list of users
    browserHistory.push("/");
}

.......
render(){
   return (
       //Add user form
       <button onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}>Add User</button>
   );
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from `browserHistory`, you can use `hashHistory` also by importing it from `react-router`.

```
import {hashHistory} from 'react-router';

hashHistory.push('/addUser')
```

Comment: Attempted import error: 'hashHistory' is not exported from 'react-router'.
this is my error