# How to handle the navigation for the Button click in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I am implementing a new app. Currently, I am able to do the navigation for the Link and couldn't do it for the button click navigation. I have checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40079797/reactjs-navigation/40080108) and tried with BrowserHistory option. But this method is currently not supported.

**Code:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {Route,Router,NavLink,HashRouter,BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";
import Contact from "./components/Contact";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import EnquiryResult from "./components/EnquiryResult";
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class MainStack extends Component {

  onClick(){
   // browserHistory.push("/EnquiryResult");
}

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        <div>
          <button className="btn" onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}>Enquiry</button >
          </div>

          <ul className="header">
            <li><NavLink  to="/contact">Contact</NavLink ></li>
            <li><NavLink  to="/Home">Home</NavLink ></li>
          </ul>

          <div>
            <Route path="/Home" component={Home}/>
            <Route path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
            <Route path="/EnquiryResult" component={EnquiryResult}/>

        </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MainStack;
```

navigation is working fine for the contact and Home. But couldn't achieve the navigation for the Enquiry. How can I achieve this button navigation?

Comment: Is your MainStack wrapped in BrowserRouter or not?

Comment: yeah. MainStack is wrapped with BrowserRouter .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your MainStack is wrapped in BrowserRouter you can use history like this:

```
onClick = () => this.props.history.push("/EnquiryResult");
```

And for the button:

```
<button className="btn" onClick={this.onClick}>Enquiry</button>
// No need to bind since we are using arrow function for our onClick.
```

Comment: I am getting an error as "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

Comment: What do you see when you `console.log(this.props)`? By the way, a simple working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/5mv52vy374

Comment: Now I have changed my index.js file as per your example and it is working fine for me.

Comment: LINK IS NOT WORKING, PLEASE TELL ME HOW TO FIX THIS "cannot read property 'push' ERROR?

Answer (score 7):

Using `useHistory()` from `react-router-dom`

```
import React from 'react';
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
function NavigationDemo() {
  const history = useHistory();
  const navigateTo = () => history.push('/componentURL');//eg.history.push('/login');

  return (
   <div>
   <button onClick={navigateTo} type="button" />
   </div>
  );
}
export default NavigationDemo;
```

Answer (score 2):

Correct way to navigate using context in react-router v4:

this.context.router.history.push('/EnquiryResult')

The new react-router v4 has changed the location of the push method when accessing this.context.router. router now has history and route as properties and it is within history that you will find the allocated method.

Also, if you are using the latest react version 15.5.0, propTypes have been removed into a separate package and you can get them with:

```
npm install prop-types --save

or

yarn add prop-types
```

Change the code like below

```
onClick(){
   this.context.router.history.push('/EnquiryResult')
}
```

Additionally, contextTypes needs to be declared as below

```
  static contextTypes = {
    router: PropTypes.object
  }
```

Comment: I am getting an error as "Cannot read property 'history' of undefined". Which library needs to be imported?

Comment: can you install prop-types ?

Comment: I have already installed the prop-types. Now the navigation is working fine  after 
 importing (import PropTypes from "prop-types";) and declaring the contextTypes.

Comment: Thanks prabhu!!! Now  it is working fine for me with contextTypes declaration. I have updated the answer with contextTypes declaration

Comment: @Subburaj  Yes it's correct i forget to add contextTypes declaration  thanks for your update

Comment: Good answer, just add the link to the docs, always link references to make a great one!

Answer (score 2):

In `react-router-dom` v6 `useHistory()` function is replaced by `useNavigate()`. So using useHistory will lead you to this error:

```
Attempted import error: 'useHistory' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'
```

So just replace `useHistory` with `useNavigate` ex:

```js
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
export default function QuestionAnswer() {
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    return (
          <Button
                onClick={() => {
                  navigate(`/something`)
                }}
              >
                Click Me
          </Button>
    )
}
```

See more detail in this [Attempted import error: 'useHistory' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62861269/attempted-import-error-usehistory-is-not-exported-from-react-router-dom) question

Answer (score -1):

You will need to import from `react-router` in order to get `browserHistory` work

```
import {browserHistory} from 'react-router';
```

Should work now

```
 onClick(){
   browserHistory.push("/EnquiryResult");
 }
```