# Attempted import error: 'useHistory' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

useHistory giving this error:

> Failed to compile ./src/pages/UserForm/_UserForm.js Attempted import
> error: 'useHistory' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'. This
> error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.

react-router-dom version:

> 4.3.1

Code:

```
import React, { useState, Fragment } from 'react';
import FormUserDetails from './FormUserDetails';
import FormPersonalDetails from './FormPersonalDetails';
import Confirm from './Confirm';
import Success from './Success';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import { Grid, makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';


function UserForm() {
    const [step, setStep] = useState(1);
    const history = useHistory();


    const StepButtons = (props) => (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Grid item xs={4}>
                {props.value !== 'initial' ?
                    <Button variant="outlined" className={classes.button} onClick={(e) => previousStep(e)}>Back</Button> :
                    <Button variant="outlined" className={classes.button} onClick={(e) => reGenerate(e)}>Re-generate</Button>
                }
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={4} />
            <Grid item xs={4}>
                {
                    props.value === 'confirm' ?
                        <Button variant="outlined" className={classes.button} style={{ float: "right" }} onClick={(e) => confirm(e)}>Confirm</Button> :
                        props.value !== 'final' ?
                            <Button variant="outlined" className={classes.button} style={{ float: "right" }} onClick={(e) => nextStep(e)}>Continue</Button> :
                            null
                }
            </Grid>
        </React.Fragment>

    );
    const nextStep = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setStep(prevState => prevState + 1)
    }
    const previousStep = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setStep(prevState => prevState - 1)
    }
    const reGenerate = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    const confirm = (e) => {
        history.push('/')
    }
    return (
         <div>
            <h1>Hello</h1>
         </div>
    )
}
export default UserForm
```

Comment: What about React version? Please note: You need to be using React >= 16.8 in order to use `useHistory` hook!

Comment: React version is already 16.8.4. Thanks for pointing out the 'react-router-dom' version. @norbitrial

Answer (score 753, accepted):

In **react-router-dom v6** `useHistory()` is replaced by `useNavigate()`.

You can use:

```js
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
const navigate = useNavigate();
navigate('/home');
```

Comment: Here you are hardcoding the page to be opened. How to get history here so that I can navigate the user to the previous page ?

Comment: I spent more than enough time digging around on react-routers Github profile and couldn't find anything noting the replacement of 'useHistory'...maybe it's there after all, but it wasn't obvious. Thanks for making this obvious!

Comment: @ShashankAC Agreed, it's not that obvious. See my answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71394655/842238

Comment: @SammyPayne Agreed, it's not that obvious. See my answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71394655/842238

Comment: They absolutely did not need to change that. Now my employer has to pay me to spend time to play the catchup game with react-router team, as if they are my competitor. Component maintainers should not make life more difficult for the people using their components. Standard engineering courtesy.

Comment: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-navigate

The navigate function has two signatures:

Either pass a To value (same type as <Link to>) with an optional second { replace, state } arg or
Pass the delta you want to go in the history stack. For example, navigate(-1) is equivalent to hitting the back button.

Answer (score 130):

Replace **useHistory** with **useNavigate**
then

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
```

and then replace `history.push('/path')` with `navigate('/path')`

Change `history.replace('/path')` with `navigate('/path', { replace: true })`

Want to use `state` in **push/navigate** do `navigate('/path', { state: { name:'Xyz' }})`

Comment: Do you mean useNavigate(), because useNavigation() gives not an exported member error.

Answer (score 46):

None of the answers actually mention how to replicate the methods which used to be available from the v5 `useHistory` hook but which are no longer available in v6 e.g. `goBack`, `goForward`, `go`. The following example is taken from the [migration guide](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/docs/upgrading/v5.md#use-usenavigate-instead-of-usehistory):

#### React Router v5 app using methods from `useHistory` hook:

```
// This is a React Router v5 app
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  const { go, goBack, goForward } = useHistory();

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => go(-2)}>
        Go 2 pages back
      </button>
      <button onClick={goBack}>Go back</button>
      <button onClick={goForward}>Go forward</button>
      <button onClick={() => go(2)}>
        Go 2 pages forward
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

#### Here is the equivalent app with v6 using `navigate` method from `useNavigate` hook:

```
// This is a React Router v6 app
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => navigate(-2)}>
        Go 2 pages back
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => navigate(-1)}>Go back</button>
      <button onClick={() => navigate(1)}>
        Go forward
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => navigate(2)}>
        Go 2 pages forward
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: > Attempted import error: 'useHistory' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'.
useHistory is no more exported member, V6 uses `useNavigate()`

Comment: @M.AbdullahIqbal Thanks for your message, yes, my answer already says to use `useNavigate()` for v6.

Answer (score 32):

### `useHistory` is replace by `useNavigate` in v6.

Just replace useHistory name to useNavigate, or follow these 3 simple steps.

1. `import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom' ;` on the top of your file.
2. `const navigate = useNavigate();` define in your function.
3. `navigate("/path_name");` redirect to your path.

Answer (score 16):

I upgraded the version of react-router-dom to

> 5.2.0

and it is working now.

Comment: Right, `useHistory` was launched in `5.2.0`

Answer (score 10):

**V6** has scrapped **useHistory** hook. now **useNavigate** hook is used.
**Usage**

```
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';
```

let say you have a function name sendData

```
function sendData(){
    let data = {name,email,password}
    let results = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/register',{
        method:'POST',
        headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept':'application/json'
        },
        body:JSON.stringify(data)
    });
    results = await results.json();
    console.warn("results",results);
    localStorage.setItem('user',JSON.stringify(results))
    navigate('../add',{replace:true})
}
```

**To Go Back** use `navigate('../add',{replace:true})` 
**To Go Forward** use `navigate('/add')`

Answer (score 9):

Just replace useHistory with useNavigate this way:

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
```

Then

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
```

Last,

```
navigate("/home");
```

Answer (score 8):

Based on above answers am adding an additional points if the issue exists with `v5`

If you stick to `react-router-dom` `v5`, You have to upgrade to `5.2.0` and the issue will be resolved, because it was introduced in the `5.2.0`

---

Or you can upgrade to `v6` and use the `useNavigate` instead of `useHistory`

```js
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const navigate = useNavigate();

navigate('/home');
```

Answer (score 7):

```js
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const navigate = useNavigate();

const confirm = (e) => {
    navigate.push('/')
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: looks like this doesn't work anymore eg. "is not a function" - on v6

Answer (score 5):

In react-router-dom v6 useHistory() function is replaced by useNavigate().

**const navigate = useNavigate();**

**navigate("/login")**

Answer (score 4):

If you must stick to the latest react-router-dom v6.0.0, then replace useHistory with useNavigate. Else, downgrade your react-router-dom to v5.2.0 and your code works as it should.

Answer (score 4):

the newer version has useNavigate, which u can import from 'react-router-dom'

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with the help of supporting information

Answer (score 2):

**react-router-dom v5** `useHistory`, but in `v6` you should use `useNavigate` hook

**Usage:**

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function SignupForm() {
  let navigate = useNavigate();

  async function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    await submitForm(event.target);
    navigate("../success", { replace: true });
  }

  return <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>{/* ... */}</form>;
```