# opening a new page in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to do this function where once the user successfully lands on the page, it will update their details in firebase, and then right away go to the landing page. but I cannot get to the landing page. here's what I have, and all the different methods ive tried:

```
 const successPage = () => { 

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if(user) {
    //   console.log("profile.js " + user.uid)
    //   userID = user.uid
      console.log("calling success page : " + user.uid)


        firestore.collection("profiledata").doc(user.uid).update({
            accountStatus: "active"
        }).then (() => {
            // window.open(routes.LANDING)
            <Route path="/"></Route>
            // window.location.href(routes.LANDING)
        //    history.push(routes.LANDING)
        })
    
  }
  
  })
  return (
    <input type="hidden"></input>
  );
  
}
```

it all works, no errors other then the error that it doesn't like `history.push`, or `this.props.history.push`, `or window.location.href`... the only thing it likes is `window.open`, but I cant use this because it opens a new window! Plz help :)

Comment: What do you mean by "don't like"?

Comment: @Eldshe retruns an error

Comment: Open the react router docs and look for how to redirect. Use any of the two methods.

Comment: Did you use "history" as should? you first import the `useHistory` hook module and name it "history" and **then** use it like you did

Comment: I imported this: `import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";` and set useHistory = to this: `let history = useHistory();` but got the error `Attempted import error: 'useHistory' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'.`

Comment: Try updating `react-router-dom` package

Comment: @Eldshe I tried that as well, it actually says its on version `6.14.11`, which I think is the newest one! Not sure why this isn't working 

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/66971821/5734311 (I googled the error message)

Comment: @ChrisG I tried that too, but it gave same export error. I posted an answer to my question  below if you would like to see

Comment: You can use <Redirect>  component from react to redirect to the landing page.

Answer (score 0):

I found out my own error. I did this:

```
 const successPage = props => { 

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if(user) {
    //   console.log("profile.js " + user.uid)
    //   userID = user.uid
      console.log("calling success page : " + user.uid)


        firestore.collection("profiledata").doc(user.uid).update({
            accountStatus: "active"
        }).then (() => {
            // window.open(routes.LANDING)
            // <Route path="/"></Route>
            // window.location.href(routes.LANDING)
        //    history.push(routes.LANDING)
           props.history.push('/')
        })
    
  }
  
  })
  return (
    <input type="hidden"></input>
  );
  
}
```

in the very first line, I brought in `props`, and it worked