# How come I can't navigate to the next page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to navigate to another component upon the `Food Truck` button being clicked.  In the `nextPage()` function, I'm trying to make that happen but it just keeps throwing me an error.

How can I go from page to the next when clicking a button?

Note:  I want to go to a totally different page, not stay on the same page.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import fire from "../../config/Fire";
import classes from "./Home.css";
import Aux from "../../hoc/Aux";
import Taco from "../../components/taco/Taco";

class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      taco: {}
    };
  }

  nextPage() {
    return this.state.taco ? <Taco /> : <Home />;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Aux>
        <h1 className={classes.ChooseTruck}>Choose your favorite truck!</h1>
        <button
          type="button"
          className="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg btn-block"
          onClick={this.nextPage}
        >
          Food Truck
        </button>
      </Aux>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: you should use `react-router` for navigation

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40079797/reactjs-navigation/40080108) for more information on routing in React.

Comment: @FK82 I'll look into that, thanks for sharing.  But how come it doesn't work the way I'm doing it?

Comment: @sp92 Idk. What you do right now is called [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) which is super standard. I don't see why it wouldn't work unless something else also went wrong. Can you post the error?

Comment: @FK82 The error I'm getting in the console (upon clicking the button) says: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined` and it's pointing to the line that contains: `return( this.state.taco ? <Taco/> : (<Home/>));`.  I had a feeling that this was the line causing the problem.

Comment: @sp92 Seems like your `nextPage` method is not bound to the instance. Try binding `nextPage` to the component instance in the constructor: i.e. add this line to the constructor body `this.nextPage = this.nextPage.bind(this);`.

Comment: @sp92 Does it work now, though? :D

Comment: @FK82 ah I tried that before, but it didn't work :(

Comment: @FK82 Hey, I got it to work :) Check my answer!

Comment: @sp92 Binding `taco` will throw an error (and it's unnecessary to bind it). But otherwise, that's it. 

Answer (score 1):

Hey guys I figured out what I did wrong :D Here's how you conditionally render if anyone else needs a reference on how to do so :D.

-I had to bind taco in the constructor i.e. `this.taco = this.taco.bind(this);`

-Create a state called `flag` and set it equal to `false` i.e. `this.state {flag: false}`

-Inside the `nextPage()` method, I had to set the state to true in order to be used later i.e. `this.setState({flag: true});`

-Inside `render()`, I set a variable called `flag` equal to the state of flag i.e. `const flag = this.state.flag;` which WAS initially false but afterwards set to true upon clicking the button which invokes `nextPage()`

-Finally, we check if `flag` is set equal `true`.  If it's true, then return the component I'm trying to navigate to which's `<Taco/>`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import fire from '../../config/Fire';
import classes from './Home.css';
import Aux from '../../hoc/Aux';
import Taco from '../../components/taco/Taco';

class Home extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.taco = this.taco.bind(this);
    this.state = {
        flag: false
    }
}

nextPage() {
    this.setState({flag: true});
}

render() {
    const flag = this.state.flag;

    if(flag) {
      return <Taco/>;
    }

    return (
        <Aux>
            <h1 className={classes.ChooseTruck}>Choose your favorite truck!</h1>
            <button
                type="button"
                className="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg btn-block"
                onClick={this.nextPage}>Food Truck
            </button>
        </Aux>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: Earlier you tried to return component in handler. You could use setState (to save in state.taco next component) and use this.state.taco in render.

This is simple schema - you can use array/object to display more 'steps'/views - w/o using routing.

Comment: @sp92 I just spent the better half of an hour working on your tic-tac-toe board, and you deleted your question! :( I implemented the entire thing using redux, and redux-saga (For the side-effects of the delayed AI click). You can see the updated sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/oq5r251o1z), and play around with it.

Comment: @FrankerZ haha, I'm sorry, I was trying so hard to come with a solution myself and I deleted out of frustration.  But thanks a lot, greatly appreciated.  I shouldn't have deleted in the 1st place.  I undeleted it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to navigate to different screen with just pure React library. If you only use React without any navigation libraries, it means that you can only have a SPA(Single Page Application).

Try to research this github link https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router. Or just navigate to the official documentation in here https://reacttraining.com/react-router/.

Comment: SPA includes also navigation within different states (so screens if you like to call them in this way)